# Extend the border of MUI Select around another element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, material-ui, border

I have a dropdown menu using MUI `Select` to sort (A-Z, newest-oldest), and I have a button next to it to reverse direction (Z-A, oldest-newest). Is it possible to extend the border of the Select (which darkens on hover) around the `IconButton`?

Here's a gif of what currently happens: [border highlights on hover but goes back to normal when cursor moves to button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg9qj.gif).

If I just change the `Paper` both elements are in to `variant="outlined"`, the outline cuts right through the label of the `Select`, whereas the Select's outline leave a gap for the label:

[image: Outline cuts right through the label of the Select] [image: If both Paper and Select are outlined, the border doubles around the Select AND cuts through its label] [image: The Select's outline leave a gap for the label]

If it's not possible to extend the Select's outline around the button, then can I make a new border around the whole element that has the same behavior on hover -- but without doubling the width of the border around the Select? Or can I make a border just around three sides of the little nubbin that's sticking out with the IconButton in it? How might I do that?

Here's the relevant part of my code for that component:

```
return (
    <FormControl sx={{ minWidth: "152px", mt: 1, }} >
        <Paper sx={{ bgcolor: "#fefcf9", }}>
        <InputLabel id="arrange-by-label">Arrange By</InputLabel>
        <Select
            labelId="arrange-by-label"
            id="arrange-by"
            value={litTextsOrder}
            label="Arrange By"
            onChange={handleLitTextsOrder}
            sx={{ bgcolor: "#fefcf9", minWidth: "132px" }}
        >
            {valuesArr.map((valueArr, index) => {
                return (
                    <MenuItem 
                        key={index} 
                        value={valueArr[0]}
                    >
                        {valueArr[1]} 
                    </MenuItem>
                )
            })}
        </Select>
        <Box component="span">
        <IconButton>
            <CompareArrowsIcon sx={{ transform: "rotate(90deg)"}}/>
        </IconButton>
        </Box>
        </Paper>
    </FormControl>
)
```

Thanks for your help, y'all!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by target the next element using `& + span` selector, remove the border right border of the `Select` and add a border except the left side in the  button next to the `Select`. The hover color is not in a theme, it's hardcoded at [this](https://github.dev/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/OutlinedInput/OutlinedInput.js#L40) line, so you also have to copy it.

```
const theme = useTheme();
const hoverColor =
  theme.palette.mode === "light"
    ? "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23)"
    : "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.23)";
const activeColor = theme.palette.primary.main;
```

```
<Select
  label="Arrange By"
  sx={{
    bgcolor: "#fefcf9",
    minWidth: "132px",
    "& fieldset": {
      borderTopRightRadius: 0,
      borderBottomRightRadius: 0
    },
    "&&:hover fieldset": {
      borderRight: "none",
      borderLeft: `solid 1px ${hoverColor}`,
      borderTop: `solid 1px ${hoverColor}`,
      borderBottom: `solid 1px ${hoverColor}`
    },
    "&&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
      borderRight: "none",
      borderLeft: `solid 1px ${activeColor}`,
      borderTop: `solid 1px ${activeColor}`,
      borderBottom: `solid 1px ${activeColor}`
    },
    "& + span": {
      display: "flex",
      borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius + "px",
      borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
      borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,

      "& button": {
        height: "100%"
      }
    },
    "&:hover + span": {
      borderColor: hoverColor,
      border: `solid 1px ${hoverColor}`,
      borderLeft: "none"
    },
    "&.Mui-focused + span": {
      borderColor: activeColor,
      border: `solid 1px ${activeColor}`,
      borderLeft: "none"
    }
  }}
>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thank you so much for this, NearHuscarl! It didn't entirely work, but I'm going to keep playing with the. I'm super grateful to you for showing me how to tackle this problem!

Comment: @alec can you fork my working codesandbox and reproduce the problem?

Comment: will do. I should be able to get to it on Monday